# Read excel data depending on one column and feed to java class

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, testng

I am currently extracting my data from excel sheet and passing to my Tests using dataProvider annotation of testNG. my code for returning the data from excel is as follows.

```
public static Object [][] excelData(String filepath) throws Exception {
   File excelFilePath = new File (filepath);
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excelFilePath);

   HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
   HSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Data");

   int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum()+1;
   int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
   Object[][] data = new Object[rowNum][colNum];

   for (int i=0; i<rowNum; i++){
     HSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
     for (int j=0; j<colNum; j++){
        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
        Object value =(Object) cellToString(cell);
        data[i][j] = (Object)value;
      //  System.out.println("The value is " + value);

     }
   }

   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));

   return data;
}
```

.

```
public static Object cellToString(HSSFCell cell){
   int type;
   Object result;
   type = cell.getCellType();

   switch(type) {
    case 0://numeric value in excel
        result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        break;
    case 1: //string value in excel
        result = cell.getStringCellValue();
        break;
    case 2: //boolean value in excel
        result = cell.getBooleanCellValue ();
        break;
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("There are not support for type with id ["+type+"] of cell");
   }

   return result;
 }
```

current excel look like below

[image: actual Excel]

I need the username and password to be passed based on last column as per below

[image: expected excel]

Comment: Why not just use [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) to get your cell's value as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently reads all cells.

In excel file there may be different sized columns. If you get only size of the first row, you will lose some cell values of the rows (greater than the first row coulmn size). 
Instead of `int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();` you should write your own method to find the greatest column size as at the below. Call this method `int colNum = getMaxColumnNum(ws);`

```
public static int getMaxColumnNum(HSSFSheet ws) {
    int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
    int max = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
        temp = ws.getRow(i).getLastCellNum();
        if (max < temp)
            max = temp;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Also you method name is `cellToString()` but it returns Object, you should change its name with `getCellValue()`.

Comment: you are right thank you..included the change suggested